# Does my URL violate RFC 3986 (or others)

Tags: http, url, path, rfc

Our system directs users to a relative path in this format:

```
/some_path/?query=string
```

The server then responds to said path.  Is that URL in violation of the RFC that anyone can tell?  (I believe [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) applies.)

Specifically, is the previous path OK, even though it doesn't specify a filename, as in:

```
/some_path/file?query=string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're showing is probably OK. Here's more detail:

Your question is a tiny bit vague - You're referring to a URL, but what you're showing us isn't technically a URL or URI. A URL or URI has to be of this syntax:

```
scheme://authority/path?query#fragment
eg: http://host.domain.ext/path/to?query=1#anchor1
```

What you appear to be returning is a **relative-ref** or perhaps (depending on where you're returning it, e.g. in an XML body) an **href**

So what you appear to be returning (according to RFC 3986) is a **relativeURI**. the RFC shows this as:

```
relativeURI    | relative-part [ "?" query ] 
relative-part = "//" authority path-abempty
                / path-absolute
                / path-noscheme
                / path-empty
```

Which is fine, in some cases.

According to the [HTTP RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) - some header values may be returned as a **relativeURI** such as Content-Location and Referer, while others (Such as Location) are defined as REQUIRING an absoluteURI. Having said that, most browsers and other clients will accept a relativeURI there.

Yes, a path with no 'filename' in your case is probably fine, and is a valid relativeURI (a relative part with an added query string). You may have any valid characters as a path, including a trailing slash if desired (although this is used to represent hierarchy, so be careful).

Comment: You may want to look at the HTTPbis specs, in particular http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/185

Comment: Ahh, so it's OK now to return a relativeURI or relative-part?

Comment: Kylar: yes, it's ok according to the new specs (which are work-in-progress)